# Can Guava's MediaType be used in the HTTP response header Content-Type?

Tags: java, http, http-headers, guava, mime-types

Guava has a utility class for media type declarations ([MediaType](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html)).  However, it states in the Javadocs:

> Note that this specifically does not represent the value of the MIME Content-Type header and as such has no support for header-specific considerations such as line folding and comments.

What does this mean?  From what I can tell, the representation of media types is exactly the same as what's used in the Content-Type header.  What will the problem be if I'm setting the Content-Type field using MediaType instances?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that as long as you're using some HTTP request API to set the Content-Type from the `MediaType`, you're fine, as that'll take care of any header-specific concerns.